# Android, different sizes in for same size in sp in code in xml

Tags: android, textview, size

good day,

I was wondering, probably i do something wrong but i don't get it.

i defined

```
<dimen name="title">16sp</dimen>
```

When i set it in xml with something like

```
<TextView android:textSize="@dimen/title"/>
```

i get a different size (smaller) then when i set it in code.

```
int mTitleSize = res.getDimension(R.dimen.title);
textView.setTextSize(mTitleSize );
```

I also tried

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mTitleSize);
```

But that results in the same text size (still biger then the textview in xml.

Does anyone has the same experience/encoutered the same probleem and have a solution (or just a solution)?

Thanks

Comment: You do realise that `textView.setHeight(mItemHeight)` sets the height of the `TextView`, and not the text size of the content? What happens if you call `textView.setSize(mTitleSize)` in stead? From memory, `getDimension()` should already deal with the unit conversion.

Comment: Damn, I'm really sorry about that, i made a copy paste mistake. And as fat as i can know this should do it but it doesn't....